# How to replicate strings from a vector differently in R?

Tags: r, repeat, replicate

I have this vector:

```
Photoperiod <- c("Day","Sunset","Night","Sunrise")
```

I would like to create a vector in which `Day` is repeated 12 times, `Sunset` 2 twice, `Night` 8 times and `Sunrise` twice until I get a vector of length equal to 168.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 7):

What about:

```
rep(rep(c("Day","Sunset","Night","Sunrise"), c(12, 2, 8, 2)), length.out = 168)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option using one `rep` and recycling technique.

```
x <- character(168)
x[] <- rep(Photoperiod, c(12, 2, 8, 2))
```